# Is this character from an anime series?

Tags: angels-feather

[image]

I saw this character way back on the internet and based a character in my story on his physical appearance. A friend of mine told me that she saw that character from an anime but wasn't sure from where. So, is this character from an anime series or just a fanart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is Christopher "Kurisu" Ousaka from [*Angel's Feather*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel's_Feather):

[image]

> His full name is Christopher. Kurisu is Shou and Kai's cousin, to the fact that his father's brother was the father of Kai and Shou. He is the Crown Prince of Winfield Kingdom. In episode 1, Chris is seen as a roommate with Kai, although it seems that there's more to their relationship. Like his cousins, Chris is white-winged, and later escapes with Sena and Shion from Winfield Kingdom. His birthday is on October 12. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angel's_Feather#Characters)